# "Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined" when no argument is provided

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have this code to add/remove the *streaming* role when a user types `?stream <user>` 
It works fine when this happens the whole command is entered, but when only `?stream`

```
if (!member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'streaming')) {
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined
```

and i have no idea why?

this is the code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const member = message.mentions.members.first();

    if (command === 'stream') { 
        if(message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_ROLES")){
            if (!member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'streaming')) {


                member.roles.add('744292301874135122')
                message.channel.send('`Added streaming role.`')
            } else 
                member.roles.remove('744292301874135122') && message.channel.send('`Removed streaming role.`')
            
        } else message.channel.send('`You dont have permission.`')
    }
});
```

Comment: What is `member.roles.cache`?

Comment: in `member.roles.cache.some`, somehow your member is undefined. debug your this line `const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();`

Comment: the error is telling you that member is undefined, so `message.mentions.members.first();` returns undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord.js can't get the member you defined in this method:

```
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
```

Because there is no mention when you just type `?stream`. So discord.js can't get the roles of the member because the member is not defined.